How to convert csv to xlsx or build a xlsx file without external libs
So, i'm using NPOI to generate an XLSX file, but i note that it's very slow with so mutch data. I've created a workaround using CSV, but it's not good.
I learning about XLSX, and i can 'understand struct' xlsx file, is many XML to build a XLSX.
I try build xlsx on thats way:
public static FileResult DownloadXlsxFile_StringBuilder(this ControllerBase controller, object data,
        string fileName = "file.xlsx")
    {
        // um arquivo XLSX nada mais é que um XLM compactado e zipado.

        if (data is IEnumerable<object> dataList)
        {
            var sheetXml = new StringBuilder();
            sheetXml.Append("""
                            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
                                        <worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
                                            <sheetData>
                            """);

            // draw header
            PropertyInfo[] props = dataList.First().GetType().GetProperties();
            sheetXml.Append("<row>");
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
            {
                sheetXml.Append($"""<c r="{(char)('A' + i)}1" t="inlineStr"><is><t>{props[i].Name}</t></is></c>""");
            }

            sheetXml.Append("</row>");

            // draw rows
            int indexRow = 1;
            foreach (var dataItem in dataList)
            {
                IEnumerable<object> values =
                    props.Select(x => dataItem.GetType().GetProperty(x.Name)?.GetValue(dataItem, null));
                sheetXml.Append("<row>");
                int indexCol = 0;
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    sheetXml.Append(
                        $"""<c r="{(char)('A' + indexCol)}{indexRow + 1}" t="inlineStr"><is><t>{value}</t></is></c>""");
                    indexCol++;
                }

                sheetXml.Append("</row>");
                indexRow++;
            }

            sheetXml.Append("</sheetData></worksheet>");

            Console.WriteLine(sheetXml.ToString());

            // draw content to Xlsx
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    // Add xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
                    var sheetXmlEntry = archive.CreateEntry("xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml");
                    using (var stream = sheetXmlEntry.Open())
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        writer.Write(sheetXml.ToString());
                    }

                    // Add xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels
                    var workbookRelsXml = archive.CreateEntry("xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels");
                    using (var stream = workbookRelsXml.Open())
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        writer.Write(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
                        <Relationships xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"">
                            <Relationship Id=""rId1"" Type=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet"" Target=""worksheets/sheet1.xml""/>
                        </Relationships>");
                    }

                    // Add xl/workbook.xml
                    var workbookXml = archive.CreateEntry("xl/workbook.xml");
                    using (var stream = workbookXml.Open())
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        writer.Write(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
                        <workbook xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"">
                            <sheets>
                                <sheet name=""Sheet1"" sheetId=""1"" r:id=""rId1""/>
                            </sheets>
                        </workbook>");
                    }

                    // Add _rels/.rels
                    var relsXml = archive.CreateEntry("_rels/.rels");
                    using (var stream = relsXml.Open())
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        writer.Write(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
                        <Relationships xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"">
                            <Relationship Id=""rId1"" Type=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument"" Target=""xl/workbook.xml""/>
                        </Relationships>");
                    }

                    // Add [Content_Types].xml
                    var contentTypesXml = archive.CreateEntry("[Content_Types].xml");
                    using (var stream = contentTypesXml.Open())
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        writer.Write(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
                        <Types xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"">
                            <Default Extension=""rels"" ContentType=""application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml""/>
                            <Default Extension=""xml"" ContentType=""application/xml""/>
                            <Override PartName=""/xl/workbook.xml"" ContentType=""application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml""/>
                            <Override PartName=""/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"" ContentType=""application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml""/>
                        </Types>");
                    }
                }

                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                return controller.File(memoryStream.ToArray(),
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("cannot convert data to IEnumerable<T> in DownloadXlsxFile");
    }

When i try to open .xlsx file with LibreOfficeCalc, i have: General Error, General Error Input/Output

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you're going to have a much easier time using an existing library that's already done the work for you and ironed out the bugs.

I highly doubt this would be faster with 'much data' instead of an existing library. Just use one.

@gunr2171 Are there any other free libraries other than an NPOI?

@Nowlights Asking for library reccomendations isn't encouraged on Stack Overflow. However, I'll give you a tip. There's a GitHub repo called Awesome Dot Net Core which lists many different libraries for different tasks. I suggest you bookmark that page, as they have an Office section that lists a few different possibilities for working with Excel files.

@rotabor Perhaps you should read the comment I'm replying to then.

Either you choose to implement the so-called Open XML format yourself based on the publicly available specifications, or you use search engines to study the ecosystem and use a library like https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK.

The code below works for me both with Excel and LibreOffice Calc.
Hard to diagnose a fault.
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

class Aclass {
    public int I { get; }
    public double D { get; }
    
    public string S { get; }
    public DateTime T { get; }
    public Aclass(int i, double d, string s, DateTime t) { I = i; D = d; S = s; T = t; }
}

static class Program {

    static void Main() {
        List<Aclass> objs = [new Aclass(1, 1.6, "Gc", new DateTime(1940, 6, 12)),
            new Aclass(2, 2.7, "E", new DateTime(2000, 1, 22, 16, 25, 17)),
            new Aclass(3, 3.1, "Pi", new DateTime(1920, 9, 4))];
        CsvToXlsx(objs);
    }

    public static bool CsvToXlsx(IEnumerable<object> data, string fileName = "file.xlsx") {
        var sheetXml = new StringBuilder();
        bool result = false;
        sheetXml.Append("""
                            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
                                        <worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
                                            <sheetData>
                            """);
        var asd = data.First();
        PropertyInfo[] props = data.First().GetType().GetProperties();
        sheetXml.Append("\r\n<row>");
        for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++) {
            sheetXml.Append($"""<c r="{(char)('A' + i)}1" t="inlineStr"><is><t>{props[i].Name}</t></is></c>""");
        }
        sheetXml.Append("</row>\r\n");
        int indexRow = 1;
        foreach (var dataItem in data) {
            IEnumerable<object> values =
                props.Select(x => dataItem.GetType().GetProperty(x.Name)?.GetValue(dataItem, null));
            sheetXml.Append("<row>");
            int indexCol = 0;
            foreach (var value in values) {
                var val = ""; 
                switch (props[indexCol].PropertyType.Name) {
                    case "String": val = $""" t="inlineStr"><is><t>{value}</t></is>"""; break;
                    case "DateTime": val = $""" s="2"><v>{((DateTime)value).ToOADate()}</v>"""; break;
                    case "Int32": case "Double": val = $"""><v>{value}</v>"""; break;
                }
                sheetXml.Append(
                    $"""<c r="{(char)('A' + indexCol)}{indexRow + 1}"{val}</c>""");
                indexCol++;
            }

            sheetXml.Append("</row>\r\n");
            indexRow++;
        }
        sheetXml.Append("</sheetData></worksheet>");
        // Console.WriteLine(sheetXml.ToString());
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true)) {
                // Add xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
                var sheetXmlEntry = archive.CreateEntry("xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml");
                using (var stream = sheetXmlEntry.Open())
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                    writer.Write(sheetXml.ToString());
                }

                // Add xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels
                var worksheetRelsXml = archive.CreateEntry("xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels");
                using (var stream = worksheetRelsXml.Open())
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                    writer.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
<Relationships xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships""></Relationships>");
                }

                // Add xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels
                var workbookRelsXml = archive.CreateEntry("xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels");
                using (var stream = workbookRelsXml.Open())
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                    writer.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
<Relationships xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"">
<Relationship Target=""styles.xml"" Type=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles"" Id=""rId3""/>
<Relationship Target=""worksheets/sheet1.xml"" Type=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet"" Id=""rId1""/>
</Relationships>");
                }

                // Add xl/workbook.xml
                var workbookXml = archive.CreateEntry("xl/workbook.xml");
                using (var stream = workbookXml.Open())
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                    writer.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
<workbook xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"" xmlns:r=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"" xmlns:mc=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"" xmlns:x15=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main"" xmlns:xr=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision"" xmlns:xr6=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision6"" xmlns:xr10=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision10"" xmlns:xr2=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2"" mc:Ignorable=""x15 xr xr6 xr10 xr2"">
<fileVersion appName=""xl"" lastEdited=""7"" lowestEdited=""7"" rupBuild=""27628""/>
<workbookPr defaultThemeVersion=""202300""/>
<mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"">
<mc:Choice Requires=""x15"">
<x15ac:absPath xmlns:x15ac=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/ac"" url=""C:\Users\ashatikhin\Documents\My Projects\Stackoverflow\Excel\""/>
</mc:Choice>
</mc:AlternateContent>
<xr:revisionPtr revIDLastSave=""0"" documentId=""13_ncr:1_{6061A8F0-A696-4E68-B28C-0B5D47BE4AA6}"" xr6:coauthVersionLast=""47"" xr6:coauthVersionMax=""47"" xr10:uidLastSave=""{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}""/>
<bookViews>
<workbookView xWindow=""-120"" yWindow=""-120"" windowWidth=""29040"" windowHeight=""18240"" xr2:uid=""{E848225D-D00B-4CE1-9C05-A44E208BC384}""/>
</bookViews>
<sheets>
<sheet name=""Sheet1"" sheetId=""1"" r:id=""rId1""/>
</sheets>
<calcPr calcId=""191029""/>
<extLst>
<ext xmlns:x15=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main"" uri=""{140A7094-0E35-4892-8432-C4D2E57EDEB5}"">
<x15:workbookPr chartTrackingRefBase=""1""/>
</ext>
<ext xmlns:xcalcf=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2018/calcfeatures"" uri=""{B58B0392-4F1F-4190-BB64-5DF3571DCE5F}"">
<xcalcf:calcFeatures>
<xcalcf:feature name=""microsoft.com:RD""/>
<xcalcf:feature name=""microsoft.com:Single""/>
<xcalcf:feature name=""microsoft.com:FV""/>
<xcalcf:feature name=""microsoft.com:CNMTM""/>
<xcalcf:feature name=""microsoft.com:LET_WF""/>
<xcalcf:feature name=""microsoft.com:LAMBDA_WF""/>
<xcalcf:feature name=""microsoft.com:ARRAYTEXT_WF""/>
</xcalcf:calcFeatures>
</ext>
</extLst>
</workbook>");
                }

                // Add xl/workbook.xml
                var styleSheetXml = archive.CreateEntry("xl/styles.xml");
                using (var stream = styleSheetXml.Open())
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                    writer.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
<styleSheet xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"" xmlns:mc=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"" xmlns:x14ac=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac"" xmlns:x16r2=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/02/main"" xmlns:xr=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision"" mc:Ignorable=""x14ac x16r2 xr"">
<fonts count=""1"" x14ac:knownFonts=""1"">
<font>
<sz val=""11""/>
<color theme=""1""/>
<name val=""Aptos Narrow""/>
<family val=""2""/>
<charset val=""204""/>
<scheme val=""minor""/>
</font>
</fonts>
<fills count=""2"">
<fill>
<patternFill patternType=""none""/>
</fill>
<fill>
<patternFill patternType=""gray125""/>
</fill>
</fills>
<borders count=""1"">
<border>
<left/>
<right/>
<top/>
<bottom/>
<diagonal/>
</border>
</borders>
<cellStyleXfs count=""1"">
<xf numFmtId=""0"" fontId=""0"" fillId=""0"" borderId=""0""/>
</cellStyleXfs>
<cellXfs count=""4"">
<xf numFmtId=""0"" fontId=""0"" fillId=""0"" borderId=""0"" xfId=""0""/>
<xf numFmtId=""16"" fontId=""0"" fillId=""0"" borderId=""0"" xfId=""0"" applyNumberFormat=""1""/>
<xf numFmtId=""14"" fontId=""0"" fillId=""0"" borderId=""0"" xfId=""0"" applyNumberFormat=""1""/>
<xf numFmtId=""20"" fontId=""0"" fillId=""0"" borderId=""0"" xfId=""0"" applyNumberFormat=""1""/>
</cellXfs>
<cellStyles count=""1"">
<cellStyle name=""Normal"" xfId=""0"" builtinId=""0""/>
</cellStyles>
<dxfs count=""0""/>
<tableStyles count=""0"" defaultTableStyle=""TableStyleMedium2"" defaultPivotStyle=""PivotStyleLight16""/>
<extLst>
<ext xmlns:x14=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main"" uri=""{EB79DEF2-80B8-43e5-95BD-54CBDDF9020C}"">
<x14:slicerStyles defaultSlicerStyle=""SlicerStyleLight1""/>
</ext>
<ext xmlns:x15=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main"" uri=""{9260A510-F301-46a8-8635-F512D64BE5F5}"">
<x15:timelineStyles defaultTimelineStyle=""TimeSlicerStyleLight1""/>
</ext>
</extLst>
</styleSheet>");
                }

                // Add _rels/.rels
                var relsXml = archive.CreateEntry("_rels/.rels");
                using (var stream = relsXml.Open())
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                    writer.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
<Relationships xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"">
<Relationship Target=""xl/workbook.xml"" Type=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument"" Id=""rId1""/>
</Relationships>");
                }

                // Add [Content_Types].xml
                var contentTypesXml = archive.CreateEntry("[Content_Types].xml");
                using (var stream = contentTypesXml.Open())
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                    writer.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
<Types xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"">
<Default Extension=""bin"" ContentType=""application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.printerSettings""/>
<Default Extension=""rels"" ContentType=""application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml""/>
<Default Extension=""xml"" ContentType=""application/xml""/>
<Override PartName=""/xl/workbook.xml"" ContentType=""application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml""/>
<Override PartName=""/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml"" ContentType=""application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml""/>
<Override PartName=""/xl/styles.xml"" ContentType=""application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml""/>
</Types>");
                }
            }
            memoryStream.Flush(); memoryStream.Position = 0;
            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)) memoryStream.WriteTo(fs);
        }
        result = true;
        return result;
    }
}


I think neither of Excel/LibreOffice works as they were not designed for ASP.NET.
